# Discord bot, embeded welcome message not working

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I am coding a discord bot but I came into a problem, I am very new to this and I am trying to learn.
I am trying to get this welcome message to work, but it just won't, any ideas?

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();
const token = "HIDDEN";
const rules = " Coming Soon ";
var prefix = "/";

client.on('ready', () => {
  console.log("Azorf is online!");
});

client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
  let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setDescription(':tada: **' + member.user.username + '** joined ' + member.guild.name)
    .setFooter('We are now ' + member.guild.memberCount)
  member.guild.channels.get('822024147202080771').send(embed)
});

client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content.toLowerCase() === '/rules') {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    embed.setColor('#bd0000');
    embed.setTitle("Server Rules");
    embed.addField("These are the rules of the server:", rules);
    message.channel.send({embed});
  }
});

client.login(token);
```

Comment: Do you get some kind of error? Can you be more specific?

Comment: No, sadly enough I did not, is there somewhere I can check for an error besides the cmd?

Comment: So you don't have access to the cmd? Is the message sent at all or just nothing happens? There could be a lot of reasons why it doesn't work.

Comment: Do you have `SERVER MEMBERS INTENT` enabled?

Comment: Yes, I just enabled it and it sadly enough still does not work, is there anything else i need to do?

Comment: I do have access to the cmd, only there is no error that shows, no message is sent at all.

Comment: Why do you surround the embed variable with curly braces?

Comment: I will remove that and try again, thanks

Comment: Hey i got this error: https://pastebin.com/4s4zQjyQ

Comment: Hey I changed the code to:  https://pastebin.com/yDDLEjnx

Comment: `member.guild.channels.get('822024147202080771').send(embed)` You're missing `.cache` before `.get` here.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is due to guildMemberAdd not firing when you don't have the Members intent enabled in the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/application), you can also troubleshoot your event by manually emitting the guildMemberAdd event.

```
if (message.content.toLowerCase() === '/join') {
    client.emit('guildMemberJoin', message.member)
}
```